# OMP for loop condition not a simple relational comparison

Tags: c++, openmp

I have this program that isn't compiling due to `error: condition of OpenMP for loop must be a relational comparison ('<', '<=', '>', '>=', or '!=') of loop variable 'i'`, referring to `for (size_t i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)`. How can I modify and fix it without affecting performance? Is this an issue due to having an old OpenMP version? (Because I remember having a different issue before on another computer with an older version that is resolved now.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    size_t n;
    if (sscanf(argv[1], "%zu", &n) == 0)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    auto *prime = new size_t[n + 1];
    for (size_t i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        prime[i] = i;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
        for (size_t j = i * i; j <= n; j += i)
            prime[j] = 0;
    size_t N = 0;
    for (size_t i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        if (prime[i] != 0)
            N++;
    std::cout << N << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Take the sqrt once?

Comment: Note that there is a race condition in your algorithm: `prime[j]` cannot be written in parallel safely. The access need to be either atomic or protected with lock (making it slower but this is the price to pay for a correct code)

Comment: I noticed it's not parallelizing well. Not a big deal here, just a test, the parallel version of this algorithm works qualitatively differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop after the `#pragma omp parallel for` have to be a [canonical form](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu40.html#x63-1260002.9.1) to be confirming. In your case the problem is with the test expression, which should be one of the following:

```
var relational-op b
b relational-op var
```

So, you have to use what was suggested by @Yakk: calculate the `sqrt` of `n` and compare it to `i`:

```
const size_t max_i=sqrt(n);
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (size_t i = 2; i <= max_i; i++)
  ....
```